# one ylabel for all subplots matlab

Tags: matlab, label, subplot

How can set a 'big, single' ylabel for multiple subplot figure in matlab?

I tried to search but only found a similar question with 'matplotlib' not with matlab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create only one `ylabel` (say, for the first subplot) and then use [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634923/align-the-ylabel-in-subplots) to align it.

Comment: @EitanT: I tried to use 'position' property of label to position it in the middle of the y-axis of all subplots but it seems fixed. Can you suggest me the coordinate of the 'position' property for a '2 row' subplot. Many thanks.

Comment: I have done it for me with the same 'position' property. It was just the matter of adjusting the position according to the label ticks. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here something that could help you:

```
MyBox = uicontrol('style','text');
set(MyBox,'String','Your YLabel')
set(MyBox,'Position',[0,0,10,10])
```

You can add other properties to rotate it and change the background color.

Edit:

Well i didn't find any ways of doing the rotation with the uicontrol. The other option is to use the `text` command :

```
%your subplot
h = axes('Position',[0 0 1 1],'Visible','off'); %add an axes on the left side of your subplots
set(gcf,'CurrentAxes',h)
text(.1,.45,'Your YLABEL',...
'VerticalAlignment','bottom',...
'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'Rotation', 90, 'FontSize',18)
```