# Common xlabel/ylabel for matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following plot:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(5,2,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=fig_size)
```

and now I would like to give this plot common x-axis labels and y-axis labels. With "common", I mean that there should be one big x-axis label below the whole grid of subplots, and one big y-axis label to the right. I can't find anything about this in the documentation for `plt.subplots`, and my googlings suggest that I need to make a big `plt.subplot(111)` to start with - but how do I then put my 5*2 subplots into that using `plt.subplots`?

Comment: With the update to the question, and the comments left in the answers below this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963035/pyplot-axes-labels-for-subplots

Comment: Not really, since my question is for plt.subplots(), and the question you link to uses add_subplot - I can't use that method unless I switch to add_subplot, which I would like to avoid. I _could_ use the plt.text solution which is given as an alternative solution in your link, but it is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: To elaborate, as far as I understand, plt.subplots cannot generate a set of subplots within an existing axis environment, but always creates a new figure. Right?

Comment: A most elegant solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963035/pyplot-axes-labels-for-subplots

Comment: Your link was provided by user Hooked more than 4 years ago (just a few comments above yours). As I said previously, that solution pertains to add_subplot, and not plt.subplots().

Comment: I open a feature request in github: http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11147

Comment: For those who wonder why several comments above link to another slightly different question, it happens that one of the answers is actually relevant in the case where `plt.subplots` is used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542971/1878788 It involves adding a larger subplot using `add_subplots` (that will receive the labels), **after** creating the initial subplots. "Switching" to `add_subplot` to create the initial subplots is not required.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

This looks like what you actually want. It applies the same approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6981055/3753826) to your specific case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 6))

fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'common X', ha='center')
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'common Y', va='center', rotation='vertical')
```

[image: Multiple plots with common axes label]

Comment: note that 0.5 for the x-coordinate of the x-label doesn't put the label at the center of the center subplot.  you'd need to go slightly larger than that to account for the yticklabels.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36542971/2550114) for a method that doesn't use `plt.text`. You create your subplots, but then add one bit plot, make it invisible, and label its x and y.

Comment: Thanks, worked in general. Any solution to breakage when using `tight_layout`?

Comment: @serv-inc with `tight_layout` replacing `0.04` with `0` seems to work.

Comment: Using `fig.text` is not a good idea. This messes up things like `plt.tight_layout()`

Answer (score 174):

Since I consider it relevant and elegant enough (no need to specify coordinates to place text), I copy (with a slight adaptation) [an answer to another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542971/1878788).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(6,15))
# add a big axis, hide frame
fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
# hide tick and tick label of the big axis
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', which='both', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
plt.xlabel("common X")
plt.ylabel("common Y")
```

This results in the following (with matplotlib version 2.2.0):

[image: 5 rows and 2 columns subplots with common x and y axis labels]

Comment: Due to simplicity this should be the accepted answer. Very straightforward. Still relevant for matplotlib v3.x.

Comment: I would like to know how could it be used with multiple figure objects? fig.xlabel("foo") does not work.

Comment: FYI: Now that people use dark themes in StackOverflow, the labels can barely be read so its better to export your png's with white background

Comment: @xyzzyqed I didn't know there was such a thing as "themes" in stackoverflow, and I don't even remember how I exported the figure. How can I control the background when exporting?

Comment: By default in plt.savefig the keyword `transparent=False`. The other plots in this thread all have white backgrounds. Maybe what you did was `plt.show` and click the 'save' button?

Comment: The only problem of this solution is that it does not work when using `constrained_layout=True` because it creates overlapping labels. In this case you have to manually adjust the borders of the subplots.

Comment: Completely remove hidden axis use: `plt.axis('off')`

Comment: You can also use the `loc` argument of `xlabel` to set it to either `center`, `left`, or `right`, e.g.,  `plt.xlabel("common X", loc="center")`

Answer (score 165):

**New in Matplotlib v3.4** (`pip install matplotlib --upgrade`)

**supxlabel** and **supylabel**

```py
    fig.supxlabel('common_x')
    fig.supylabel('common_y')
```

See example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for tl, cl in zip([True, False, False], [False, False, True]):
    fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=cl, tight_layout=tl)

    gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 3)

    ax = dict()

    ax['A'] = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0:2])
    ax['B'] = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0:2])
    ax['C'] = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 2])

    ax['C'].set_xlabel('Booger')
    ax['B'].set_xlabel('Booger')
    ax['A'].set_ylabel('Booger Y')
    fig.suptitle(f'TEST: tight_layout={tl} constrained_layout={cl}')
    fig.supxlabel('XLAgg')
    fig.supylabel('YLAgg')
    
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[see more](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html)

Comment: Neat, but seems to have problems with plt.tight_layout() where things overlap. When I try to change the x argument for f.supxlabel(), it screws up the margins too.

Comment: Make sure to use Python 3.7 or above in order to be able to install v 3.4 of `matplotlib`

Comment: You'd still need to use a text element to add multiple supylabels for different locations

Comment: If things overlap with `tight_layout`, try to supply the `rect` parameter, e.g. to increase the left margin: `fig.tight_layout(rect=(0.025,0,1,1))`

Comment: It's the best canonical solution.

Answer (score 46):

Without `sharex=True, sharey=True` you get:

[image]

With it you should get it nicer:

```
fig, axes2d = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3,
                           sharex=True, sharey=True,
                           figsize=(6,6))

for i, row in enumerate(axes2d):
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        cell.imshow(np.random.rand(32,32))

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

But if you want to add additional labels, you should add them only to the edge plots:

```
fig, axes2d = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3,
                           sharex=True, sharey=True,
                           figsize=(6,6))

for i, row in enumerate(axes2d):
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        cell.imshow(np.random.rand(32,32))
        if i == len(axes2d) - 1:
            cell.set_xlabel("noise column: {0:d}".format(j + 1))
        if j == 0:
            cell.set_ylabel("noise row: {0:d}".format(i + 1))

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Adding label for each plot would spoil it (maybe there is a way to automatically detect repeated labels, but I am not aware of one).

Comment: This is a lot harder if, for example, the number of plots is unknown (e.g. you've got a generalise plot function that works for any number of subplots).

Answer (score 18):

Since the command:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(5,2,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=fig_size)
```

you used returns a tuple consisting of the figure and a list of the axes instances, it is already sufficient to do something like (mind that I've changed `fig,ax`to `fig,axes`):

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(5,2,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=fig_size)

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xlabel('Common x-label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Common y-label')
```

If you happen to want to change some details on a specific subplot, you can access it via `axes[i]` where `i` iterates over your subplots.

It might also be very helpful to include a

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

at the end of the file, before the `plt.show()`, in order to avoid overlapping labels.

Comment: I'm sorry I was a bit unclear above. With "common" I meant one single x label below all the plots, and one single y label to the left of the plots, I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @JohanLindberg: Concerning your comments here and above: Indeed `plt.subplots()` will create a new figure instance. If you want to stick with this command, you can easily add a `big_ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`, since you already have a figure and can add another axis. After that, you can manipulate `big_ax` the way it is shown in the link from Hooked.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but if I do that, I have to add the big_ax after plt.subplots(), and I get that subplot on top of everything else - can I make it transparent or send it to the back somehow? Even if I set all the colors to none as in Hooked's link, it is still a white box covering all my subplots.

Comment: @JohanLindberg, you're right, I hadn't checked that. But you can easily set the background color of the big axis to `none` by doing: `big_ax.set_axis_bgcolor('none')` You should also make the labelcolor `none` (as opposed to the example linked by Hooked): `big_ax.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off')`

Comment: Thanks, this actually seems to work. I had already fixed it by the plt.text solution discussed earlier, but now I can change to this more elegant solution.

Comment: I get an error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'` in the statement `ax.set_xlabel('Common x-label')`. Can you figure it out?

Comment: Nice answer. Your first two code lines (ie repeating OP's) seem redundant for easy exposition. More importantly,  "axes" is maybe best not used; it can be a function built in to matplotlib. Maybe you could replace "axes" and "ax" both by "axs"?  Also, for me, axs turns out to be not a tuple but a multidimensional array (dimensions 5x2), which is a bit awkward. So I use axs=axs.reshape((5*2,1)).

Comment: To add one missing element in @Marius 's solution, while initializing, use `big_ax = fig.sub_plot(111, frameon=False)` to suppress the frame.

Answer (score 8):

It will look better if you reserve space for the common labels by making invisible labels for the subplot in the bottom left corner. It is also good to pass in the fontsize from rcParams. This way, the common labels will change size with your rc setup, and the axes will also be adjusted to leave space for the common labels.

```
fig_size = [8, 6]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=fig_size)
# Reserve space for axis labels
ax[-1, 0].set_xlabel('.', color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
ax[-1, 0].set_ylabel('.', color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
# Make common axis labels
fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'common X', va='center', ha='center', fontsize=rcParams['axes.labelsize'])
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'common Y', va='center', ha='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=rcParams['axes.labelsize'])
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice use of the invisible label! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

This feature is now part of the [proplot matplotlib package](https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subplots.html#Shared-and-spanning-labels) that I recently released on pypi. By default, when you make figures, the labels are "shared" between subplots.

---

**Original answer:**

I discovered a more robust method:

If you know the `bottom` and `top` kwargs that went into a `GridSpec` initialization, or you otherwise know the edges positions of your axes in `Figure` coordinates, you can also specify the ylabel position in `Figure` coordinates with some fancy "transform" magic.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
bottom, top = 0.1, 0.9
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, bottom=bottom, top=top)
avepos = 0.5 * (bottom + top)
transform = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(mtransforms.IdentityTransform(), fig.transFigure)  # specify x, y transform
axs[0].yaxis.label.set_transform(transform)  # changed from default blend (IdentityTransform(), axs[0].transAxes)
axs[0].yaxis.label.set_position((0, avepos))
axs[0].set_ylabel('Hello, world!')
```

...and you should see that the label still appropriately adjusts left-right to keep from overlapping with labels, just like normal, but will also position itself exactly between the desired subplots.

Notably, if you omit the `set_position` call, the ylabel will show up exactly halfway up the figure. I'm guessing this is because when the label is finally drawn, `matplotlib` uses 0.5 for the `y`-coordinate without checking whether the underlying coordinate transform has changed.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem while plotting a grid of graphs. The graphs consisted of two parts (top and bottom). The y-label was supposed to be centered over both parts.

I did not want to use a solution that depends on knowing the position in the outer figure (like fig.text()), so I manipulated the y-position of the set_ylabel() function. It is usually 0.5, the middle of the plot it is added to. As the padding between the parts (hspace) in my code was zero, I could calculate the middle of the two parts relative to the upper part.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# Create outer and inner grid
outerGrid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[1,1,1], height_ratios=[1,1])
somePlot = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1,
               subplot_spec=outerGrid[3], height_ratios=[1,3], hspace = 0)

# Add two partial plots
partA = plt.subplot(somePlot[0])
partB = plt.subplot(somePlot[1])

# No x-ticks for the upper plot
plt.setp(partA.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

# The center is (height(top)-height(bottom))/(2*height(top))
# Simplified to 0.5 - height(bottom)/(2*height(top))
mid = 0.5-somePlot.get_height_ratios()[1]/(2.*somePlot.get_height_ratios()[0])
# Place the y-label
partA.set_ylabel('shared label', y = mid)

plt.show()
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWZ9r.png)

Downsides:

- The horizontal distance to the plot is based on the top part, the bottom ticks might extend into the label.
- The formula does not take space between the parts into account.
- Throws an exception when the height of the top part is 0.

There is probably a general solution that takes padding between figures into account.

Comment: Hey, I figured out a way to do this very much in the vein of your answer, but might solve some of these issues; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/44020303/4970632 (below)