# Pandas histogram Labels and Title

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I'm trying to put x- and y-axis labels as well as a title on a three-panel histogram I  have created through Pandas, but can't seem to place it correctly. The only result I've gotten in the title and an x-axis label on the very last of the three graphs. I want one overall title, xlabel and ylabel. The code that makes the plot is below. Any suggestions?

```
df1.hist(column='human_den',by='region',sharex=True,sharey=True,layout=(1,3))
```

Comment: To just add a title and axis labels to a hist plot you can now use `plot()` function with the `kind`, `title`, `xlabel`, and `ylabel` e.g. `plot(kind='hist', title='my Title', xlabel='x axis', ylabel='y axis')`

Answer (score 15):

Following along from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots), use [`subplots`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) to create `Figure` and `axis` objects instances.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# random data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['human_den','region'])
df1['human_den'] = np.random.rand(100)
df1['region'] = np.random.choice(['Northeast', 'South', 'Midwest'], size=100)

# set up figure & axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

# drop sharex, sharey, layout & add ax=axes
df1.hist(column='human_den',by='region', ax=axes)

# set title and axis labels
plt.suptitle('Your Title Here', x=0.5, y=1.05, ha='center', fontsize='xx-large')
fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'common X', ha='center')
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'common Y', va='center', rotation='vertical')
```

Notice, the keyword arguments `sharex`, `sharey`, and `layout` are not assigned in `df1.hist()`, in favor of setting `sharex`, `sharey`, `nrows` and `ncols` in `plt.subplots` to achieve similar effects.  The important element is assigning `df.hist()`'s keyword argument, `ax`, to the previously initialized `axes` object.  The title can be set with [suptitle](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle).

[image: Shared x and shared y common label]