# How to plot 3 subplots after loading data in a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to load 3 numpy files using for loop. After loading data I want to plot 3 subplots because I want to make a comparison between them. If I don't apply for loop and load files one by one then I can easily do that. But is there any way that I load data in for loop and then make 3 subplots.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ind1 =[1,2,3]
ind2 = [4,5,6]
for i in range(len(3)):
    data1=np.load(..)
    data2=np.load(..)
    ax1.plot(data1, data2)
```

Comment: If you want to plot things in a for loop one at a time, then you should also read your files one at a time

Comment: I read one file at a time in for loop. But I want to plot them as subplot  having 3 rows and one column. So that I can make a comparison b/w plots

Comment: Ok, check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what your file contains and how they look, here is the basic idea which you can adapt to your example. Here, I store the names of the files you want to read in a list and then I loop over the subplots one at a time. I use `enumerate` to get the axis instance and the **index** so that I can access/loaf files one at a time. P.S: I used `np.loadtxt` just as an example. You can basically replace the commands with whatever way you want to load files.

Instead of `axes.ravel()`, you can also use either `axes.flatten()` or `axes.flat`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel()): # or axes.flatten() or axes.flat
    data1=np.loadtxt(files[i])
    data2=np.loadtxt(files[i])
    ax.plot(data1, data2)
plt.tight_layout() # To get a better spacing between the subplots
```

**Alternative** solution without using `ravel` and `enumerate` as suggested by [Tom de Geus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2646505/tom-de-geus) is:

```
for i in range(3):
    axes[i].plot(x, y, label='File %d' %i)
    axes[i].legend()
```

---

Following is a simple example to showcase the idea (Same can be done using the above alternative solution)

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel()): # or axes.flatten() or axes.flat
    ax.plot(x, y, label='File %d' %i)
    ax.legend()
fig.text(0.5, 0.01, 'X-label', ha='center')
fig.text(0.01, 0.5, 'Y-label', va='center', rotation='vertical')  
plt.tight_layout() # To get a better spacing between the subplots
```

[image]

Comment: Since you use an index anyway, it could be more transparent to also use it on the axes. Also you could avoid the `ravel` by not specifying `ncols` at all. (All a matter of taste of course.)

Comment: @TomdeGeus: I added your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: What if I want to set xlabel and y label only once rather than on every subplot

Comment: @herry: Have a look at the top most answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots). Let me know if that doesn't work for you. It's just a two line thing

Comment: @Bazingaa why in the fig.text command we don't mention (0.5,0). Instead of this you mentioned (0.5, 0.1). According to my understanding these are values of x and y axis. 0.5 indicate that center of the x-axis. So for y-axis value shouldn't it be 0 rather than 0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181393/discussion-between-bazingaa-and-herry).

Comment: You can also try that