# Python subplot set multiple axis properties

Tags: python, properties, axis, subplot

I am using pythons plt.subplot function to generate multiple plots. I use a loop over the axis, to generate the plots with specific data and to set the axis properties. Below, i have put a simplified example of the code workflow (figuratively) I am speaking of.

```
fig,axis =  plt.subplots(3,2) 

loop over rows:
  loop over columns:
      axis[row][col].plt(plot the data)
      axis[row][col].grid()
      axis[row][col].legend()
      axis[row][col].set_xlabel(...)
      etc...
```

so what came to my mind was, that perhaps i could set the common setup properties of the axis in a more general manner which also enhances the readability of the code. Now I know that some of the properties can be set via plt.rcParams and others via plt.setp but i thoughed a more elegant way would be the following approach to access all the axis elements in an numpy array manner

```
axis[:][:].set_xlabel(...)
```

However, i receive the following error massage: "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'"

Is there any elegant way to apply my solution or something similar in a correct way?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. Legends and labels are specific to the subplot. Grid you can set with `rcparams` globally.

If you are setting the same labels for all subplots, you might consider just setting it once like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots/5317233)