# common x label for subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to create a plot with 3 subplots. This plot should have a **common y and common x label** I followed: [Common xlabel/ylabel for matplotlib subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots).

I am however changing the aspect ratio `aspect=0.5` and this results in the x-label being too far from the plot. **Do you know how to fix this?**

[image]

***> Minimal Reproducible Example here:***

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get Data 
data1 = np.random.rand(100,100)
data2 = np.random.rand(100,100)
data3 = np.random.rand(100,100)
data = [data1,data2,data3]
# Create Figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    im = ax.imshow(data[i], origin="lower", interpolation='quadric', cmap='jet', extent=[50,250,0,400], aspect=0.5, vmin=0, vmax = 1)


cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([1, 0.35, 0.01, 0.3])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax) # orientation='horizontal'
fig.tight_layout(pad=0.7)

## add a big axis, hide frame
fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
## hide tick and tick label of the big axis
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
plt.xlabel("common X")
plt.ylabel("common Y")


plt.show()
```

Comment: There is of course `plt.xlabel("common X", labelpad=n)`, which takes negative n-values - but it is an absolute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. The idea is to create a big axis with actual extremal positions of the set of subplots. This should be flexible with different subplot settings.

[image: common label row subplots]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get Data
data1 = np.random.rand(100,100)
data2 = np.random.rand(100,100)
data3 = np.random.rand(100,100)
data = [data1,data2,data3]
# Create Figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    im = ax.imshow(data[i], origin="lower", interpolation='quadric', cmap='jet', extent=[50,250,0,400], aspect=0.5, vmin=0, vmax = 1)


cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([1, 0.35, 0.01, 0.3])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax) # orientation='horizontal'
fig.tight_layout(pad=1.5)

# Get extents of subplot
x0 = min([ax.get_position().x0 for ax in axes])
y0 = min([ax.get_position().y0 for ax in axes])
x1 = max([ax.get_position().x1 for ax in axes])
y1 = max([ax.get_position().y1 for ax in axes])

# Hidden axes for common x and y labels
plt.axes([x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0], frameon=False)
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)

# Labelize
plt.xlabel("common X")
plt.ylabel("common Y")
plt.title('Common Title')

plt.show()
# plt.savefig("example.png", bbox_inches="tight")  # save figure
```

Comment: Every time I try to export the fig (fig.savefig(...)), the colorbar is not exported. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I had to export it with `plt.savefig('figure.png', bbox_inches='tight')` in order to make the colorbar visible. If you want to avoid this issue, you may want to create axes with manual position. This could be also cause by the `tight_layout` function with the `sharex` and `shared` options to `True` at the same time in `subplots`. I added the solution in the answer.

Comment: Great ! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

Since you already defined a subplot, you can set its ratio as well:

```
## add a big axis, hide frame
allax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
allax.set_aspect(.3) #slightly smaller than 1/3 because of the colorbar
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. I just have trouble seeing where I should place your code within my code?

Comment: I just copied your code and modified it a bit - I thought your "## add a big axis, hide frame" part gave it away.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that too ! Thanks! :) Another question, every time I try to export the fig (fig.savefig(...)), the colorbar is not exported. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Independent of the file format? Matplotlib behaves sometimes differently depending on the file format. But sounds like a new question.

Comment: yes, independently of the file format. Okay, I will post a new question this evening. Thanks!