# Matplotlib figure '.supxlabel' does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, attributeerror

I'm trying to set figure labels for my conditioned hexagonal binning plot, but when I run this code I get the Attribute Error: `'Figure'object has no attribute 'supxlabel'`. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

```
zip_codes = [98188, 98105, 98108, 98126]

def hexbin_zips(ax, zipcode):
    kc_tax_zip = kc_tax_stripped.loc[kc_tax_stripped['ZipCode'] == zipcode]
    out = ax.hexbin(kc_tax_zip['SqFtTotLiving'], kc_tax_zip['TaxAssessedValue'], gridsize=30)
    return out

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 10), sharex='col', sharey='row')
axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]

for n in range(4):
    hexbin_zips(axes[n], zip_codes[n])
    axes[n].set_title(str(zip_codes[n]))

fig.supxlabel('Total Living Space in Square Feet', fontsize=16.)
fig.supylabel('Tax-Assessed Value', fontsize=16.)
```

Comment: This functionality has not yet been released. A workaround can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got into the same problem when using the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65135433/4332585).
It turns out that you need 2 things:

- Python at least version 3.7;
- Matplotlib at least version 3.4 (`pip install --upgrade matplotlib`).

If you have Python under 3.7, the install of version 3.4 of `matplotlib` won't work (at least it didn't in my case).