# Broken xx axis and adjustment of the log-normal distribution in a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, axis, axis-labels

I'm doing a histogram with broken x axis for the first time, but I'm having these problems:

1. I can't get the bars of both subplots and the xx axis range to be the same width. The right subplot appears to have a larger scale.
2. I can't put the label of the xx axis simultaneously for the two subplots. I would like to have only one centered label.
3. Some numbers of both subplots are superimposed and there are small horizontal lines in the region where the two subplots join (I cannot remove these small lines)
4. In one of the subplots the xx axis appears with commas and in the other with dots. I wish it were all commas.
5. I can't adjust a log-normal distribution and calculate the mean and standard deviation for that distribution.

I would like to understand how to make this graph because afterwards I have other similar graphs to make and could practice, but now at the beginning I am a little lost and I really needed your help. How could you solve the previous problems and adjust a log-normal distribution by determining the mean and standard deviation?

Python code (Jupyter notebook - Anaconda)

```
#amostra 17B (menor intervalo)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import scipy, pylab
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

frequencia_relativa=[0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043, 
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000]
x=[0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40, 
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80, 
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00]
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,8]
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
#fig, ax =plt.subplots()
f,(ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True, facecolor='w')
ax.bar(x, height=frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black')
ax2.bar(x, height=frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black')
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(7.0, 8.5, 0.5))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.04)
ax.set_xlim(0,3.0)
ax2.set_xlim(7.0,8.0)
# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
# This looks pretty good, and was fairly painless, but you can get that
# cut-out diagonal lines look with just a bit more work. The important
# thing to know here is that in axes coordinates, which are always
# between 0-1, spine endpoints are at these locations (0,0), (0,1),
# (1,0), and (1,1).  Thus, we just need to put the diagonals in the
# appropriate corners of each of our axes, and so long as we use the
# right transform and disable clipping.

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1-d,1+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1-d,1+d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)

ax.set_xlabel('Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', fontsize=22)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequência relativa', fontsize=22)
#x_axis = np.arange(0, 29, 0.001)
#ax.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis,2.232,1.888), linewidth=3)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('output.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Graph obtained by code:

[image]

Graphic similar to what I would like to get (but I wish mine had a broken axis):

[image]

---

Updated code and plot:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import scipy, pylab
import locale
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from scipy.stats import lognorm
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

frequencia_relativa=[0.000, 0.000, 0.038, 0.097, 0.091, 0.118, 0.070, 0.124, 0.097, 0.059, 0.059, 0.048, 0.054, 0.043, 
                     0.032, 0.005, 0.027, 0.016, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 
                     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.005, 0.000, 0.000]
x=[0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40, 
   1.50, 1.60, 1.70, 1.80, 1.90, 2.00, 2.10, 2.20, 2.30, 2.40, 2.50, 2.60, 2.70, 2.80, 
   2.90, 3.00, 3.10, 3.20, 3.30, 3.40, 3.50, 3.60, 3.70, 3.80, 3.90, 4.00, 4.10, 4.20,
   4.30, 4.40, 4.50, 4.60, 4.70, 4.80, 4.90, 5.00, 5.10, 5.20, 5.30, 5.40, 5.50, 5.60,
   5.70, 5.80, 5.90, 6.00, 6.10, 6.20, 6.30, 6.40, 6.50, 6.60, 6.70, 6.80, 6.90, 7.00,
   7.10, 7.20, 7.30, 7.40, 7.50, 7.60, 7.70, 7.80, 7.90, 8.00]
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,8]
f, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True, facecolor='w')
axes = f.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
ax.plot(x, lognorm.pdf(x,0.903,0.713), linewidth=3)
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax2.spines['top'].set_color('none')
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2,width_ratios=[3,1])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.bar(x, height=frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black')
ax2.bar(x, height=frequencia_relativa, alpha=0.5, width=0.1, align='edge', edgecolor='black')
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 18)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'minor', labelsize = 18)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(7.0, 8.5, 0.5))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.04)
ax.set_xlim(0,3.0)
ax2.set_xlim(7.0,8.0)
def func(x, pos):  # formatter function takes tick label and tick position
    s = str(x)
    ind = s.index('.')
    return s[:ind] + ',' + s[ind+1:]   # change dot to comma
x_format = tkr.FuncFormatter(func)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_format)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_format)
# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
# This looks pretty good, and was fairly painless, but you can get that
# cut-out diagonal lines look with just a bit more work. The important
# thing to know here is that in axes coordinates, which are always
# between 0-1, spine endpoints are at these locations (0,0), (0,1),
# (1,0), and (1,1).  Thus, we just need to put the diagonals in the
# appropriate corners of each of our axes, and so long as we use the
# right transform and disable clipping.

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1-d/3,1+d/3),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax2.tick_params(labelright=False)
ax.tick_params(labeltop=False)

f.text(0.5, -0.04, 'Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', ha='center', fontsize=22)
f.text(-0.02, 0.5, 'Frequência relativa', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=22)
#ax.set_xlabel('Tamanho lateral do triângulo ($\mu m$)', fontsize=22)
#ax.set_ylabel('Frequência relativa', fontsize=22)
#x_axis = np.arange(0, 29, 0.001)
#ax.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis,2.232,1.888), linewidth=3)
f.tight_layout()
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('output.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: 1) the scale on the right is 3 times bigger than on the left. So divide the width of the bars on `ax2` by three.      2) you can do by looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots)

Comment: @DavidG I have already managed to solve most problems by seeing other questions in the stack, but I cannot adjust and determine the mean and standard deviation of the log-normal. I've tried everything but I'm not getting it. Could you help me? I really appreciate it. I updated the code and plot image.