# Matplotlib: correct placement of subplot annotations?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create subplots with `Matplotlib` by looping over my data. However, I don't get the **annotations into the correct position**, apparently not even into the correct subplot. Also, the **common x- and y-axis labels** don't work.

My real data is more complex but here is an example that reproduces the error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import seaborn as sns

# create data
distributions = []
first_values = []
second_values = []
for i in range(4):
    distributions.append(np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 100))
    first_values.append(np.random.uniform(0.7, 1))
    second_values.append(np.random.uniform(0.7, 1))

# create subplot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize = (15, 10))
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color = '#76A29F', lw = 2, label = 'distribution'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], color = '#FEB302', lw = 2, label = '1st value', linestyle = '--'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], color = '#FF5D3E', lw = 2, label = '2nd value')]

# loop over data and create subplots    
for data in range(4):
    if data == 0:
        position = axes[0, 0]
    if data == 1:
        position = axes[0, 1]
    if data == 2:
        position = axes[1, 0]
    if data == 3:
        position = axes[1, 1]
        
    dist = distributions[data]
    first = first_values[data]
    second = second_values[data]
        
    sns.histplot(dist, alpha = 0.5, kde = True, stat = 'density', bins = 20, color = '#76A29F', ax = position)
    sns.rugplot(dist, alpha = 0.5, color = '#76A29F', ax = position)
    position.annotate(f'{np.mean(dist):.2f}', (np.mean(dist), 0.825), xycoords = ('data', 'figure fraction'), color = '#76A29F')
    position.axvline(first, 0, 0.75, linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = '#FEB302')
    position.axvline(second, 0, 0.75, linestyle = '-', alpha = 0.75, color = '#FF5D3E')
    position.annotate(f'{first:.2f}', (first, 0.8), xycoords = ('data', 'figure fraction'), color = '#FEB302')
    position.annotate(f'{second:.2f}', (second, 0.85), xycoords = ('data', 'figure fraction'), color = '#FF5D3E')
    position.set_xticks(np.arange(round(min(dist), 1) - 0.1, round(max(max(dist), max([first]), max([second])), 1) + 0.1, 0.1))

plt.xlabel("x-axis name")
plt.ylabel("y-axis name")
plt.legend(handles = legend_elements, bbox_to_anchor = (1.5, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

What I want is to have

1. the annotations in the correct subplot next to the vertical lines / the mean of the distribution
2. shared x- and y-labels for all subplot or at least for each row / column

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the function to make the subplot a single array (axes.flatten()) and modify it to draw the graph sequentially, you can draw the graph. The colors of the annotations have been partially changed for testing purposes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(202000104)
# create data
distributions = []
first_values = []
second_values = []
for i in range(4):
    distributions.append(np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 100))
    first_values.append(np.random.uniform(0.7, 1))
    second_values.append(np.random.uniform(0.7, 1))
    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))

legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color = '#76A29F', lw = 2, label = 'distribution'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], color = '#FEB302', lw = 2, label = '1st value', linestyle = '--'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], color = '#FF5D3E', lw = 2, label = '2nd value')]

for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    sns.histplot(distributions[i], alpha=0.5, kde=True, stat='density', bins=20, color='#76A29F', ax=ax)
    sns.rugplot(distributions[i], alpha=0.5, color='#76A29F', ax=ax)
    ax.annotate(f'{np.mean(distributions[i]):.2f}', (np.mean(distributions[i]), 0.825), xycoords='data', color='red')
    ax.axvline(first_values[i], 0, 0.75, linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = '#FEB302')
    ax.axvline(second_values[i], 0, 0.75, linestyle = '-', alpha = 0.75, color = '#FF5D3E')
    ax.annotate(f'{first_values[i]:.2f}', (first_values[i], 0.8), xycoords='data', color='#FEB302')
    ax.annotate(f'{second_values[i]:.2f}', (second_values[i], 0.85), xycoords='data', color = '#FF5D3E')
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(round(min(distributions[i]), 1) - 0.1, round(max(max(distributions[i]), max([first_values[i]]), max([second_values[i]])), 1) + 0.1, 0.1))

plt.xlabel("x-axis name")
plt.ylabel("y-axis name")
plt.legend(handles = legend_elements, bbox_to_anchor = (1.35, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this looks great. I additionally changed the xycoords to ('data', 'axes fraction') to keep the position constant between subplots.
Do you also happen to know how to create common x- and y-labels for the two rows/columns?

Comment: Try this: `fig.supxlabel('x-axis name');fig.supxlabel('y-axis name')` See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots) to this for details.

Comment: thanks again. the `suplabel` option didn't work for me (probably due to different versions of matplotlib) but I'm placing the labels manually now using `plt.annotate`...

Comment: Correct, x-axis is fig.subxlabel(), y-axis is fig.subylabel(). See here for [details](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html).