# How to share axes after adding subplots via add_subplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2], 'B': [0.1, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1], 'C': [0.2, 0.5, 0.0, 0.7], 'D': [0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6]}, index=list('abcd'))     

    A    B    C    D
a  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.6
b  0.2  0.0  0.5  0.3
c  0.5  0.3  0.0  0.4
d  0.2  0.1  0.7  0.6
```

Now I want to plot each row as a barplot whereby the y-axis and the x-tick-labels are shared using `add_subplot`.

Until now, I can only produce a plot that looks like this:
[image]

There is one problem:

The axes are not shared, how one do this after using `add_subplot`? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963035/pyplot-axes-labels-for-subplots), this problem is solved by creating one huge subplot; is there any way to do this in a different manner?

My desired outcome looks like the plot above with the only difference, that there are no x-tick-labels in the upper row and now y-tick-labels in the right column.

My current attempt is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2], 'B': [0.1, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1], 'C': [0.2, 0.5, 0.0, 0.7], 'D': [0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6]}, index=list('abcd'))

fig = plt.figure()
bar_width = 0.35
counter = 1
index = np.arange(df.shape[0])

for indi, rowi in df.iterrows():

    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, counter)
    ax.bar(index, rowi.values, width=bar_width, tick_label=df.columns)
    ax.set_ylim([0., 1.])
    ax.set_title(indi, fontsize=20)
    ax.set_xticks(index + bar_width / 2)
    counter += 1

plt.xticks(index + bar_width / 2, df.columns)
```

Comment: Do you mean *shared* as in `add_subplot(..., sharex=, sharey=)`?

Comment: @kazemakase: If these flags, `sharex=`, `sharey=`, existed in `add_subplot`, that would indeed be perfect. But I don't see such flags.

Comment: Have you tried? Or are you just saying that they don't exist because you are too lazy?

Comment: @Cleb You are right, I can't find this in the documentation either. Still, it works - at least on my machine with Matplotlib 1.5.2.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest `fig.add_subplot?` returns as potential flags (only the ones starting with s):
`sketch_params: unknown
  snap: unknown` So no, I did not try whether `sharex`, `sharey` exist as they are not listed...

Comment: See: http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#easily-creating-subplots

Comment: In the documentation of
[add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) it says *kwargs are legal Axes kwargs plus projection* and [`Axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#axes-class) does have `sharex=None, sharey=None` as arguments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973223/how-to-share-x-axes-of-two-subplots-after-they-have-been-created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question how to produce shared subplots in matplotlib:

- The [SO seach engine results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=matplotlib+sharex+add_subplot)
- The matplotlib [recipes](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#easily-creating-subplots) or the [examples page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)

What may be more interesting here, is that you could also directly use pandas to create the plot in a single line:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2], 'B': [0.1, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1], 'C': [0.2, 0.5, 0.0, 0.7], 'D': [0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6]}, index=list('abcd'))
df.plot(kind="bar", subplots=True, layout=(2,2), sharey=True, sharex=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]