# Set common xlabel for subplots on the same line

Tags: matplotlib, label, subplot

I took a look to several discussions on the site and I can't find what I want. I want to set a common xlabel to 2 subplots on the same line like this :

[image]

I tried set_xlabel(), text(), but for the first it didn't work, and for the second I can't put the text at the bottom center.

And I would like to optimize the code, if someone knows how.

My code :

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.barh(range(1, len(y)+1), y)
plt.yticks([i+1.5 for i in range(7)], range(7))
plt.xlim(0, xmax)

plt.ylabel("Y label")

plt.subplot(122)
plt.barh(range(1, len(y2)+1), y2, color="r")
plt.yticks([i+1.5 for i in range(7)], range(7))
plt.xlim(0, xmax)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common xlabel/ylabel for matplotlib subplots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots)

Comment: Already checked and already tried, but didn't work. For a 3x3 subplots, it's easy to center the xlabel, but for a 1x2 subplots, I don't know.

Comment: please explain why/how it "didn't work"

Comment: The accepted answer from the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots) works for **any** number of subplots. So it cannot be easy for 3x3 but not easy for 1x2.

Comment: @Diziet Asahi, It gave me errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150819/common-xlabel-ylabel-for-matplotlib-subplots), you can simply set some text in the middle of the figure. (This does not depend on how many subplots there are in the figure).

```
plt.gcf().text(0.5,0.04,"common xlabel for subplots on the same line", ha="center")
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randint(100,833, size=(7,2))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.barh(range(1, len(y)+1), y[:,0])
plt.yticks([i+1.5 for i in range(len(y))], range(len(y)))
plt.xlim(0, 1000)

plt.ylabel("Y label")

plt.subplot(122)
plt.barh(range(1, len(y)+1), y[:,1], color="r")
plt.yticks([i+1.5 for i in range(len(y))], range(len(y)))
plt.xlim(0, 1000)

plt.gcf().text(0.5,0.04,"common xlabel for subplots on the same line", ha="center")
plt.show()
```

---

The other option would be to create a new axes, with the frame turned off and provide a label to it, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372509/how-to-add-a-shared-x-label-and-y-label-to-a-plot-created-with-pandas-plot/42373161#42373161)

```
ax = plt.gcf().add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
ax.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off')
ax.set_xlabel('common xlabel for subplots on the same line', labelpad=8)
```

Comment: Actually when I used text(), the text was superimposed to the graphs, and even if I change x et y coordinates, it wasn't placed where I wanted. Maybe because of the gcf() you add.