# Matplotlib: turning off most axes in a 7x1 subplot, but leave the bottom (renamed) ticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a bunch of Nx1 plots made of subplots (most are 7x1, but some are 5x1, etc).  The idea is that there are 3 zones to be in, and 7 timed events of varying time lengths, and I want to see each timed event in order, with a plot of the time in minutes spent in a zone.  I want each subplot to have the proper y axes label ticks (minutes) as well as a label (P1 through P7 in this case, but some are P1 through P5, etc), but all the x axes turned off **except** for the bottom one which are my own ticks, in words.  I'm pulling from [here](https://pythonspot.com/en/matplotlib-bar-chart/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176424/hiding-axis-text-in-matplotlib-plots).

The problem I have is the bottom-most subplot not only has my word text ('Zone 1', 'Zone 2'..), but also has numbers that are meaningless for me (ticks from 0 to 1), and the y axes have the subplot ticks that are correct (going from 0 to 10 or so) but also an over-all marking from 0 to 1 which is senseless.  I want to nuke the senseless over-all x axis numbers, and the over-all senseless y axes numbers.

How do I remove the unwanted tick numbers from the over-all plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plotlist = [[0, 0, 690], [0, 0, 1030], [0, 0, 470], [30, 10, 730], [0, 0, 460], [20, 0, 540], [0, 0, 380]]
numpresses = 7

fig = plt.figure()

objects = ('Zone 1', 'Zone 2', 'Zone 3')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
plt.title('Time spent in zones (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Minutes spent in zone')

for subploti in range(numpresses):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(numpresses, 1, (subploti + 1))
    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axes.set_ylabel('P %i' %(subploti + 1))

    mins = [x / 60. for x in plotlist[subploti]]
    plt.bar(y_pos, mins, align='center', alpha=0.5)

plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
axes = plt.gca()
axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)



plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with extraneous ticks]

Comment: No, it's not the same -- that still has x axis labels on all the subplots in the photo shown.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out the solution was using shared axes and creating the number of subplots in advance and indexing them.  Needed to look harder [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963035/pyplot-axes-labels-for-subplots).  If anyone else finds this the new code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plotlist = [[0, 0, 690], [0, 0, 1030], [0, 0, 470], [30, 10, 730], [0, 0, 460], [20, 0, 540], [0, 0, 380]]
numpresses = 7

fig, axtuple = plt.subplots(numpresses, sharex=True, sharey=True) #, squeeze=True)

objects = ('Zone 1', 'Zone 2', 'Zone 3')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
plt.ylabel('Minutes spent in zone')
plt.xlabel('Distances (feet)')
axtuple[0].set_title('Time spent in zones (minutes)')

for subploti in range(numpresses):
    mins = [x / 60. for x in plotlist[subploti]]
    axtuple[subploti].bar(y_pos, mins, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    axtuple[subploti].set_ylabel('P %i' %(subploti + 1))

plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.show()
```