# Is it possible to attach a y-label to the figure and not an Axes in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm making a multiplot with 3 rows and one column. I turn off some spines and reduce the hspace to zero so that this plot with 3 axes looks like a single plot. The issue comes in, when I want to specify the ylabel. Since the height proportions are determined dynamically, based on the data, the ylabel will never be in the middle of the y-axis of my plot, no matter to which ax I attach it to. So I figured, I can just use some kind of text box type instead that I can attach to the figure instance in which all the subplots are located in anyway, but I can't find anything like that on google. My code is pretty long and isn't really required for this problem, so I'll just post a picture of my plot. All I need is for the ylabel to always be centered. How can I achieve this with a text box?

[image]

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963035/pyplot-axes-labels-for-subplots) also does the trick

Comment: Thanks no more late night coding for me...